# Extensive div child when parent grows/shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is have `child2` take 200px and be on the bottom of `parent`, and have `child1` grow/shrink as a parent grows/shrinks (zoom in/out of the page by the user for example)

example:

If `parent`'s height is `1000px`, then I want `child1`'s height to be 800px & `child2`'s height to be `200px`.

If `parent`'s height is `2000px`, then I want `child1`'s height to be `1800px` & `child2`'s height to be `200px`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to get this done. But beware: Only supported in modern browsers, see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#child1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

#child2 {
  align-self: flex-end;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This trick works using margin and padding on first child according to the second child height:

```css
#parent {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}

#child1 {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#child2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1.

To do this is very simple. If you make the child2 200px then set the child1 to 100% in height minus the 200px, child1 will take up all the space apart from the 200px that child2 is taking.

```js
alert($("#child1").height());
```

```css
#parent {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}

#child1 {
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: blue;
}

#child2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
    </div>
</div>
```

## 2.

You could also do it using javascript

You take the height of the parent and then -200. Set child 1 to be the resulting height.

```
var height = $("#parent").height() -200;
$("#child1").height(height);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g9xj0mjx/

if you then wanted to get rid of the 1000px parent height and make it a percentage so it changes when the user changes screen size (like you mentioned). You could put it inside a resize event

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var height = $("#parent").height() -200;
  $("#child1").height(height);
});
```

Comment: After Editing it works however calc is not well supported.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1**

You can do this with `absolute position` and `padding` like this:

```css
html, body {height:100%;margin:0}

#parent {
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
#child1 {
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
  padding-bottom:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#child2 {
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Solution2**

You can also use `calc()`, check the [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

```css
html, body {height:100%;margin:0}

#parent {
  height:100%;
}
#child1 {
  height:calc(100% - 200px);
  background:yellow;
}
#child2 {
  height:200px;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
    </div>
</div>
```